# How to correctly invalidate the cache in a Shopware 6 app script

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

With [custom entities](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/custom-data/custom-entities) it is possible to create your own data structures based on shopware 6's app system. So I went ahead and created my own entity which has a CRUD within the storefront. I am loading my data via twig macro on the product-page-loaded hook:

```
{# located in custom/apps/MyApp/Resources/scripts/include/my-script.twig #}
{# @var services \Shopware\Core\Framework\Script\ServiceStubs #}

{% macro load(salesChannelId, header) %}
    {% set criteria = {
        'filter': [
            { 'type': 'equals', 'field': 'salesChannelId', 'value': salesChannelId },
        ]
    } %}

    {% set myEntity = services.repository.search('ce_atl_my_entity', criteria) %}

    {% if myEntity.first is not empty %}
        {% do header.addExtension('atlMyExtension', myEntity.first) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Now the user is able to adjust this data I just loaded via the following custom storefront endpoint:

```
{# located in custom/apps/MyApp/Resources/scripts/storefront-my-script/my-script.twig #}
{# @var services \Shopware\Core\Framework\Script\ServiceStubs #}

{% do services.writer.upsert('ce_atl_my_entity', [
    {
        'id': hook.request['id'],
        'rating': hook.request['rating'],
        'url': hook.request['url'],
        'userRatingsTotal': hook.request['user_ratings_total'],
        'salesChannelId': hook.request['sales_channel_id']
    }
]) %}

{% set response = services.response.json({}) %}
{% do response.cache.tag('my-entity-' ~ hook.request['id']) %}

{% do hook.setResponse(response) %}
```

Once data gets updated I need to invalidate the cache, otherwise I am fetching stale cache items on the next product page load. Cache invalidation is described [here](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-scripts/custom-endpoints#cache-invalidation). However, it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here is my cache invalidation script:

```
{# located in custom/apps/MyApp/Resources/scripts/cache-invalidation/my-invalidation-script.twig #}

{# @var services \Shopware\Core\Framework\Script\ServiceStubs #}

{% set ids = hook.event.getIds('ce_atl_my_entity') %}

{% if ids.empty %}
    {% return %}
{% endif %}

{% set tags = [] %}
{% for id in ids %}
    {% set tags = tags|merge(['my-entity-' ~ id]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% do services.cache.invalidate(tags) %}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using custom cache tags only works when you have access to the response, which you don't have with the `product-page-loaded` hook.

You can invalidate the product detail route cache by using this pattern for the cache tag:

```
product-detail-route-{{parentId || id}}
```

So if the product has a `parentId` use that as suffix, otherwise use the `id`. That probably won't help you much though, as you won't have the product ids in the invalidation script, when you persist your custom entity.

It might honestly be easiest to simply pass the product id to your custom endpoint, to also persist the product together with your custom entity. This will invalidate the cache of the corresponding detail pages automatically.

```
{% do services.writer.upsert('ce_atl_my_entity', [
    {
        'id': hook.request['id']
    }
]) %}

{# then also persist the product to invalidate the detail page cache #}

{% do services.writer.upsert('product', [
    {
        'id': hook.request['productId']
    }
]) %}
```

#### For custom endpoints:

You are supposed to choose the tag yourself. You must therefore also [tag the response to be cached](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-scripts/custom-endpoints#cache-config) yourself. Given you have a custom storefront endpoint:

```
{# Resources/scripts/storefront-custom-endpoint/my-example-script.twig #}

{% set criteria = {
    'associations': {
        'product': {}
    }
} %}
{% set customEntity = services.repository.search('ce_atl_my_entity', criteria).first %}

{% do hook.page.addExtension('myCustomEntity', customEntity) %}

{% set response = services.response.render('@MyApp/storefront/page/custom-page/index.html.twig', { 'page': hook.page }) %}

{# here you add your own cache tag #}
{% do response.cache.tag('my-custom-tag-' ~ customEntity.id) %}

{% do hook.setResponse(response) %}
```

Then the responses of that endpoint get cached with `my-custom-tag-{id}` and you can use the same pattern to invalidate the cached responses.

```
{# Resources/scripts/cache-invalidation/my-invalidation-script.twig #}
{# ... #}

{% set tags = [] %}
{% for id in ids %}
    {% set tags = tags|merge(['my-custom-tag-' ~ id]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% do services.cache.invalidate(tags) %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I guess I misunderstood the concept but I think I got it right now. However, it is still fetching cached data on the product page loaded hook. I updated my question with more details, could you have a look at it again?

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that. You would have to enrich the tags of the product detail response, but you don't have access to it. Works only with custom endpoints. I updated the answer with a couple of possible workarounds.